# Posting to Event page?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, status

I want include some simple PHP in one of my pages, that when the page is called, it will write a new post (database driven on my end) to a Facebook Event page that I have going.

Al the DB stuff is simple , but I cannot seem to find any reference to automatically post to my event.

Has anyone accomplished this? The Graph API looks like I can create an event, invite folks and check invite status' ... but not programatically write to the events wall.

Lots of reference to write to someones wall, just not to an event specifically. Any examples I could look at ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the **feed** connection for Event as described in the [Event documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/):

> This connection corresponds to the Event's wall. You can create a link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the EVENT_ID/feed connection.